# How does Jbutton addActionListener method takes object of any type?

Tags: java, jbutton

Does addActionListener() has parameter of Object type?

Comment: You can always [read the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener-java.awt.event.ActionListener-).

Answer (score 0):

No. It has a parameter of ActionListener type. You cannot invoke `.addActionListener(new Object());`. You can invoke:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Stuff to do.
    }
});
```

You should also really read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener-java.awt.event.ActionListener-) for this.